# MC Frontalot 80085

Tags: calculation-puzzle, word-problem

MC Frontalot is a musician, and one of his songs is a word problem that seems to me like it belongs here. If you want to listen to it instead of just reading the lyrics, a quick video search of "MC Frontalot 80085" will bring it up on YouTube. Here is the full song, copied (with permission) directly from [his website](http://frontalot.com/index.php/?page=lyrics&lyricid=73):

> ### 80085
>
> Last time I had a math class, there wasn't any internet
>
> invented yet. That isn't on the level but I'll try to pique your interest
>
> with half-truths and lies.
>
> As ever, MC Frontalot feigns innocence and denies.
>
> I won't admit it. You can't make me say it:
>
> that I dropped Calc B more than a year before Mosaic.
>
> Oh no now it's out, now it's shouted from the balconies:
>
> that Frontalot's about to be engaging in some alchemy.
>
> I'll turn a string of operands into some smut.
>
> If that sort of thing's offensive to you keep eyes shut.
>
> Or better yet, don't even enter, into calculator, song.
>
> But if you're ready to be titillated, follow along.
>
> Ready? Go. Eighty women went to the podiatrist.
>
> Arrive: simultaneous. Soon the scene's riotous.
>
> Nine just leave. Those in the difference persevere,
>
> packing up the lobby very tightly, domineered
>
> by one Sally Gorey (that's her given name)
>
> (though her title is Reception) (and professional acclaim
>
> is due her) ('cause she did what needed doing). And it's done:
>
> she opened up the schedule, slotted every single one.
>
> But, um... not many on a Friday afternoon!
>
> All but an eighteenth of the women in the room
>
> had to vrooooom. For each remaining patient
>
> x-rays were taken. Then the doctor took vacation.
>
> Why was that vacation germane to the math?
>
> 'Cause of good data policy in the office and a vast
>
> abundance of caution on the part of our Sally:
>
> eight backups nightly, automated, and the tally
>
> only ever shrinking when manually deleted.
>
> All of this occurring in the box behind reception so she needed
>
> a full backup of that box, noons.
>
> These weren't incremental, so her server needs ballooned.
>
> Who deserved to flee Duluth? The doctor was in Rio
>
> for three work weeks and another Monday just to be so
>
> thoroughly relaxed upon return.
>
> Have you gathered all the facts that you needed to discern?
>
> Morning in the office, after vacatings:
>
> out of those belonging to the original 80 ladies.
>
> How many digital toes were in images grand total?
>
> Your evidence so far is largely anecdotal.
>
> And you're keen to know if any had deformity. So icky!
>
> Ten toes per customer; this puzzle: not that tricky.
>
> Key in your calc. Check your seven-segment indicator.
>
> Now add my eliteness. Notice that the sum is greater
>
> than expected. You still have to subtract
>
> two for a pair of things Sally has that I lack.
>
> I warned you it was kind of immature; I wasn't skirting the issue.
>
> Still you snicker at the calculator. "Dirty! I need a tissue."

I hope this is assumed, but I will state anyway that how you reached your answer is as important as the answer itself, and just a number (even if it's the right number) is not an acceptable answer.

Comment: Thanks for editing to identify the source and permission. It makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> already in the title: 80085.

Here are the steps to getting there:

> 80 women went to the podiatrist, of which 9 just leave. There are 71 left, plus Sally, so 72. All but an eighteenth had to leave, so 4 stayed (Sally and 3 patients). 3 patients times 2 feet, so we start with 6 pictures. Then, during each of the following 25 nights (Friday to Tuesday, 3 weeks), the number of images at the box behind the reception increases by 48 (8*6) and the complete reception box gets a backup in the 'backup box' at the noon afterwards. Now, the nightly increase happens 25 times, and the daily backup happens 24 times. That results in a total of 15750 images. The amount of toes is 15750*5, so 78750. Now add my eliteness, so 1337. This results in 80087. We have to subtract 2, so we end up with 80085.

And now in plain calculations:

> women = 80-9 = 71
>  women = 71+1 = 72
>  women = 72/18 = 4
>  patients = 4-1 = 3
>  pictures = 3*2 = 6
>  reception(1) = 54, backup(1) = 54
>  reception(2) = 102, backup(2) = 156
>  reception(3) = 150, backup(3) = 306
>  reception(4) = 198, backup(4) = 504
>  reception(5) = 246, backup(5) = 750
>  reception(6) = 294, backup(6) = 1044
>  reception(7) = 342, backup(7) = 1386
>  reception(8) = 390, backup(8) = 1776
>  reception(9) = 438, backup(9) = 2214
>  reception(10) = 486, backup(10) = 2700
>  reception(11) = 534, backup(11) = 3234
>  reception(12) = 582, backup(12) = 3816
>  reception(13) = 630, backup(13) = 4446
>  reception(14) = 678, backup(14) = 5124
>  reception(15) = 726, backup(15) = 5850
>  reception(16) = 774, backup(16) = 6624
>  reception(17) = 822, backup(17) = 7446
>  reception(18) = 870, backup(18) = 8316
>  reception(19) = 918, backup(19) = 9234
>  reception(20) = 966, backup(20) = 10200
>  reception(21) = 1014, backup(21) = 11214
>  reception(22) = 1062, backup(22) = 12276
>  reception(23) = 1110, backup(23) = 13386
>  reception(24) = 1158, backup(24) = 14544
>  reception(25) = 1206
>  totalimages = 1206+14544 = 15750
>  toes = 15750*5 = 78750
>  elitetoes = 78750+1337 = 80087
>  answer = 80087-2 = 80085