# What sequence of steps do these lyrics encode?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, music

This is a sort of reverse puzzle in that the answer is given, and the question is - what steps are needed to get to the answer?

The MC Frontalot song titled [80085](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyPlrAxqGWk) encodes a series of mathematical steps which, presumably, result in the number "80085" (which number may be mildly titillating when viewed on a calculator):

> Ready? Go. Eighty women went to the podiatrist.
>   Arrive: simultaneous. Soon the scene's riotous.
>   Nine just leave. Those in the difference persevere,
>   packing up the lobby very tightly, domineered
>   by one Sally Gorey (that's her given name)
>   (though her title is Reception) (and professional acclaim
>   is due her) ('cause she did what needed doing). And it's done:
>   she opened up the schedule, slotted every single one.
>   But, um... not many on a Friday afternoon!
>   All but an eighteenth of the women in the room
>   had to vrooooom. For each remaining patient
>   x-rays were taken. Then the doctor took vacation.
>
> Why was that vacation germane to the math?
>   'Cause of good data policy in the office and a vast
>   abundance of caution on the part of our Sally:
>   eight backups nightly, automated, and the tally
>   only ever shrinking when manually deleted.
>   All of this occurring in the box behind reception so she needed
>   a full backup of that box, noons.
>   These weren't incremental, so her server needs ballooned.
>   Who deserved to flee Duluth? The doctor was in Rio
>   for three work weeks and another Monday just to be so
>   thoroughly relaxed upon return.
>   Have you gathered all the facts that you needed to discern?
>
> Morning in the office, after vacatings:
>   out of those belonging to the original 80 ladies.
>   How many digital toes were in images grand total?
>   Your evidence so far is largely anecdotal.
>   And you're keen to know if any had deformity. So icky!
>   Ten toes per customer; this puzzle: not that tricky.
>   Key in your calc. Check your seven-segment indicator.
>   Now add my eliteness. Notice that the sum is greater
>   than expected. You still have to subtract
>   two for a pair of things Sally has that I lack.
>   I warned you it was kind of immature; I wasn't skirting the issue.
>   Still you snicker at the calculator. "Dirty! I need a tissue."

My question is: what series of steps do these lyrics encode? All my attempts thus far have failed to produce the desired output.

Comment: It already starts off bizarrely, unless I'm missing something: 80 minus 9 = 71, and an eighteenth of 71 is not a whole number.

Comment: @Claudiu but an eighteenth of 72 is.

Comment: 72/18 = 4 last I checked

Comment: @Matt (80 - 9 + 1[sally]/18 = 4 - 1 [sally isn't a patient] = 3 women (x-rayed); my bad

Comment: @Raystafarian: Oooh nice! I forgot about Sally. And so it begins . . .

Comment: The overall result should be a factor of 10 because it says "Ten toes per customer". I don't see how you can reach 80085

Comment: Add the eliteness - 1337.  So 78750 + 1337 = 80087.  Take away 2 is 80085,  Just dont know how to get to 78750.

Comment: @Trenin: It may also be `31337`, which means you have to reach `48750`

Comment: @Claudiu Think not. Check my answer.

Comment: This is a repeat of http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17573/mc-frontalot-80085?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ready? Go. Eighty women went to the podiatrist.

80

> Nine just leave. Those in the difference persevere,

80 - 9 = 71

> All but an eighteenth of the women in the room

There are 72 women including sally, so 4 remain including sally.  Thus there are 3 patients.

72 / 18 = 4

4 - 1 = 3

> For each remaining patient
>   x-rays were taken. Then the doctor took vacation.

Then x-rays are taken and the doctor goes on vacation.

> eight backups nightly, automated, and the tally

So eight backups were taken each night.

> All of this occurring in the box behind reception so she needed

All eight backups were copied to a single box.

> a full backup of that box, noons.

And *that* box was also backed up on noon every day.

> These weren't incremental, so her server needs ballooned.

Ok, here is where it gets tricky.  After all the x-rays are taken, we have 3 sets of xrays.  That night, 8 backups are taken, so we add 24 x-rays to the box behind reception.  The next noon, we back up that entire box, so all 27 get copied to a server.  Repeat the next night and so on.

Lets ignore the inital 3 for a minute.  Each night, the backups add 24 images to the box behind reception.  The following noon, all those are backed up to a server.

So, we get the following:

$$Server=\sum_{i=1}^{24}{24 \times i}=7200$$
$$Reception=25\times24=600$$

Now we need to re-introduce those original 3 xrays.  They are present on the reception server so add 3 to it.

$$Reception=603$$

Also, we included them 24 times on the server, so add that as well.

$$Server=7200+24\times3=7272$$

The total number of images is therefore $603+7272=7875$.

> Ten toes per customer; this puzzle: not that tricky.

7875 x 10 = 78750

> Now add my eliteness. Notice that the sum is greater

78750 + 1337 = 80087

> You still have to subtract
>   two for a pair of things Sally has that I lack.

80087 - 2 = 80085

Which is

> 7-segment display ("Still you snicker at the calculator.") for "BOOBS": a pair of things that Sally has that the puzzler lacks.